# Query String URL Filter

Tags: query-string

I'm having issues doing a basic query string filter and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I keep getting these two messages:

> "Cannot save all of the property setting for this Web Part.  An error
>   has occurred."

and

> "Enter a valid Query String parameter name.  Special characters and
>   spaces are not allowed.

I've tried the following:

```
list address?Filter=Value

list address?FilterField1=Filter&FilterValue1=Value
```

and I've tried the plain filter name and value name but also tried going to the column settings and used the column setting page as the filter name.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the Query String Filter web part, but with the URL's in the format you've given

```
list address?FilterField1=Filter&FilterValue1=Value
```

you don't actually need to add the Query string Filter web part - its will work on any normal list view without it.

Comment: Thanks.  What will work on any normal list view?  I didn't type the url in the example.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Basically, I want it to work like the Categories page in the blog template. The page that just shows the posts for a specific category.

Comment: I want to make a page that just shows data from a specific category from a list with data that has several categories of data.

Comment: @ryan is that possible to filter the view based on content type? like view has task and task summary content type based item now i need only task items.